# Why can't I run the example from storm-starter using this command?

Tags: maven, maven-2, apache-storm

I've have had no experience using Storm or Maven before, and I'm working on my starter project. When I compile the starter project uploaded on the git website using the command given there i.e. this:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.classpathScope=compile -Dexec.mainClass=storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
```

I can run the Exclamation topology class, but when I use this command:

```
java -cp ./target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
```

I can't run it.

By the way, I got the second command from the maven tutorial on apache's site
Could someone point out what am I doing wrong here?

PS: This is the error http://pastebin.com/A1PQbB3r

Comment: How do you know you can't run it?  What's the error?

Comment: @ChrisGerken this is the error: http://pastebin.com/A1PQbB3r   Comment edited for clarity with new pastelink

Comment: I don't know the starter project, but I think the storm dependency is missing. Can you link the pom.xml ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your pom probably has the scope for the storm dependency as "provided" which means that it will be in the runtime classpath, but not in the jar-with-dependencies.  Try changing the scope to "compile"

Comment: as I said, I'm just starting with Storm and Maven, and I looked at a few tutorials to get be off the ground and none of them explicitly explained what the dependency scope is and what you can put there. I just looked it up now online and now I know. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting the java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError since the storm jars are not in your classpath. For your second command, put the storm jar and the storm/lib in your classpath and it should work as expected.

Comment: Hi str1k3r, that didn't work.
Got the same thing: http://pastebin.com/wGsyMYFQ
You're talking about adding the storm jar file and it's lib folder that was downloaded from the github repo right?

Comment: i looked at the pastebin and it seems you are still not running the command as expected. you added 0.8.2 in your $PATH

(edit, hit enter accidentally)
run the following command:
java -cp ./target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:/Users/xxx/storm-0.8.2/storm-0.8.2.jar:/Users/xxx/storm-0.8.2/lib/*:/Users/xxx/storm-0.8.2/conf/storm.yaml storm.starter.ExclamationTopology

Comment: hi. You were saying that using the compile scope would cause problems in the cluster mode. Could you elaborate on that?

Comment: can you also have a look at this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16928884/why-can-i-run-this-file-packaged-by-maven-by-specifying-the-path-as-argument-but

Answer (score 0):

The scope for the Storm dependency should be different depending on whether your are running in local mode or cluster.

For local mode you need to set the scope to "compile" or leave the  tag empty as scope defaults to "compile".

In order to submit your topology to a cluster you need to set the scope to "provided", otherwise the Storm jar will be packaged inside your topology jar and when deploying to the cluster there will be 2 Storm jars in the classpath: the one inside your topology and the one inside the Storm installation directory.

Comment: But, if you do not want to put the storm jar file one the cluster, and just want to run it from the jar file packaged by maven, then you could still keep it as compiled right? I haven't tried clustered mode yet, but I'm just asking.