# Why can I run this file packaged by Maven by specifying the path as argument but not by setting the path permanently in my path variable?

Tags: java, maven, path, maven-2

So, I was trying to run this command:

```
java -cp ./target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
```

To run the ExclamationTopology class in ./storm/starter/ but it didn't work.

Then [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16903185/why-cant-i-run-the-example-from-storm-starter-using-this-command/16905073?noredirect=1#comment24400451_16904295) on SO suggested me to change the command to this:

```
java -cp ./target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar:/Users/xxx/storm-0.8.2/storm-0.8.2.jar:/Users/xxx/storm-0.8.2/lib/*:/Users/xxx/storm-0.8.2/conf/s torm.yaml storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
```

And it worked. So I thought that I just had to add those paths to the path variable and that would do it, so I changed my path and this is what it looks like now:

```
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/xxx/storm-0.8.2/storm-0.8.2.jar:/Users/xxx/storm-0.8.2/lib/*:/Users/xxx/storm-0.8.2/conf/s​torm.yaml
```

But I still can't get the first command running. Can anyone please tell me why?
What I basically want is to get the first command running; it just somehow needs the correct path set, right? I believe that's exactly what I've done.

EDIT:

This is the error returned in the first command:

```
$ java -cp ./target/storm-starter-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar storm.starter.ExclamationTopology
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: backtype/storm/topology/IRichSpout
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: backtype.storm.topology.IRichSpout
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:202)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
```

Comment: What error did the first command return?

Comment: The system path and the Java classpath are two different things. system binaries are found in the first and in the second Java class files.

Comment: @ChrisGerken you answered the same question I've linked to yesterday. Anyway, I've added the error.

Comment: @jeppi, ok wait let me look that up.

Comment: What does this have to do with maven?

Comment: @tieTYT I'm not sure if it does or not. I'm trying to run a class in a jar file packaged by Maven, so I wasn't sure if there something I had to do differently here just because I had used Maven. Please excuse me if it sounds dumb, I was just playing safe.

Comment: @jeppi @Chris Gerken ok so I changed my classpath variable to this: `$ echo $CLASSPATH
/Users/aruparel/Summer Project/storm-0.8.2/storm-0.8.2.jar:/Users/aruparel/Summer Project/storm-0.8.2/lib/*:/Users/aruparel/Summer Project/storm-0.8.2/conf/storm.yaml
`. It should work now right? Still doesn't..

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to add the storm dependencies to your classpath - it's currently not included because it is marked as 'provided' in the m2-pom.xml, change it to 'compile':

```
<dependency>
<groupId>storm</groupId>
<artifactId>storm</artifactId>
<version>0.8.2</version>
<scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
```

Comment: You are answering the other question, which was answered months ago.